# yacc (bison) ast simplification

Tags: yacc, abstract-syntax-tree

Lets say i have a part of my .y grammar like this:

```
stmt : expr { $$ = $1; }
      | stmt expr { $$ = insert_stmt_list($1, $2); }
```

where i can have a statement that gives an expression, or i can have several expressions that results in a statement list.
About the latter i store it through the insert_stmt... function, however the first i send it to the top of the stack.

My question is: how do i deal with the $$ = $1 ?
I mean, the insert_stmt_list puts everything in a structure and i know it's there and i can print their values and so on, but where the hell does the $$ = S1 goes to? How to read it? :-)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: *how to read it?*

You have a left recursive grammar which first has to recognize an `expr`.  This is reduced to `stmt` and the semantic value produced by `make_new_stmt_list` becomes that of the `stmt1` by means of `$$ = $1;`.

That just means "take the semantic value of the first symbol from the right side (which happens to be the only one) and propagate it as the semantic value of the left side".

Then if another `expr` is seen, the parse continues with the other production:

```
stmt : ...
     | stmt expr { $$ = insert_stmt_list($1, $2); }
```

Here, the `$1` coming from the `stmt` on the right hand side is the semantic value which was assigned to `$$` in the prior reduction which produced `stmt`.

You have designed the system so that an `expr` functions as a `stmt`. Moreover, an `expr` produces a value that is suitable as either argument to `insert_stmt_list`: expressions are lists.

So:

1. If your input has just one expression E, then the `stmt` which emerges is just that expression.
2. If you have two expressions E1 and E2, then the `stmt` which emeges is the result of:

   ```
   insert_stmt_list(E1, E2)
   ```
3. If you have three expressions, then the overall `stmt` is the result of these calls:

   ```
   insert_stmt_list(insert_stmt_list(E1, E2), E3)
   ```

and so on. Whether that makes sense depends on the semantics of this "insert" operation.

Comment: The big question was in fact if i was expecting a statement, how to deal with a expression instead? I was able to deal with this using a generic struct where i have a flag {is_STATEMENT, is_EXPRESSION, ... } and a pointer to the respective struct. All this because C doesn't allow to know the type of a pointer.

Comment: You can look at Lisp abstract syntax. The basic syntactic unit of evaluation is the expression. If you want several expressions to be evaluated for their side effect where a single expression is expected, you have an operator for that like `progn`: `(progn expr1 expr2 ... exprn)`. This is not a superfluous node.

Answer (score 0):

It's more idiomatic to write something like this:

```
stmt : expr { $$ = make_new_stmt_list($1); }
      | stmt expr { $$ = insert_stmt_list($1, $2); }
```

One way or another, you'll need to wrap your expression data structure in a statement list data structure.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you are creating a statement list when for ast (abstract syntax tree) purposes, you are supposed to discard pointless nodes. That's why i got to the conclusion that putting the value on the top of the stack $$=$1 was the way to go, but then everything became blurry :-)

Comment: The distinction between a list of expressions and a single expression isn't necessarily pointless, however. That is the sort of thing that is found in abstract syntax. The way *you* have it in fact fails to abstract; your code is taking the grammar literally.  I.e. `stmt : expr` asserts that, syntactically, a statement is an expression, and so you've converted that to `$$ = $1`. A more abstract view is that this left-recursive production is just a "jig" for building a sequence (which could just have one element in it).